# How to Rotate HTML List Element that are Rendered Horizontally with their List Style Bullets Aligned?

Tags: html, css

With CSS and HTML, I am having trouble styling `ul` and its `li` elements such that the following happen:

1. The `ul` and constituent elements are rendered horizontally instead of vertically.
2. The `li` retain their bullet styling.
3. The `li` are rotated -45 degrees.
4. The `li` bullets start on the same vertical plane and similar with the `li` text.

So far, I can make no. 1-3 happen.  So far, making no. 4 happen is beyond my knowledge.  The problem seems to be that the `li` have different content lengths.

The end goal should look approximately like this hand-drawn image: [image].  Please ignore that the text becomes smaller in the attached image.  That was an artifact of the tool I used.

I have tried:

```css
li {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  float: left;
}
```

with:

```html
<ul>
    <li>aaa
    </li>
    <li>aaaaaa
    </li>
    <li>aaaaaaaaaa
    </li>
    <li>aaaaaaaaaaaaa
    </li>
    <li>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    </li>
</ul>
```

It yields something like this, which I don't want:

[image]

Bonus points if you can make a horizontal line run through the bullet points as well as you see in the intended diagram.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use `transform-origin` to rotate around a particular point

```css
li {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  transform-origin: bottom left
}

ul {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>aaa
  </li>
  <li>aaaaaa
  </li>
  <li>aaaaaaaaaa
  </li>
  <li>aaaaaaaaaaaaa
  </li>
  <li>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's beautiful.  Thank you!  Is there a sustainable way to have the list place the elements more closely together?  I'm imagining that there is a bounding box being drawn around the elements, which is what is preventing that from happening?